# Sum of similar elements in 2D associative array - PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, associative-array

I have an array like below

```
Array (
        [0]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1009
                   [employee_name] =>Jane Doe
                   [amount]        =>4500.00
                )
        [1]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1009
                   [employee_name] =>Jane Doe
                   [amount]        =>2500.00
                )
        [2]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1033
                   [employee_name] =>Test User
                   [amount]        =>3455.50
                )
        [3]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1009
                   [employee_name] =>Jane Doe
                   [amount]        =>5500.00
                )
        [4]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1033
                   [employee_name] =>Test User
                   [amount]        =>7500.00
                )
     )
```

What I want to get is an array like below:
(One entry per each user with the **sum of their amount values**.) I know I have to use a for-each, but cannot really understand how to merge the entries of [employee_num] and [employee_name]. I don't know the number of similar entries or their indexes in the array beforehand.

```
Array (
        [0]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1009
                   [employee_name] =>Jane Doe
                   [amount]        =>12500.00
                )
        [1]=> Array
                (
                   [employee_num]  =>1033
                   [employee_name] =>Test User
                   [amount]        =>10955.50
                )
      )
```

How can I do this? Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sumAmount($data)
{
    $rst=array();
    foreach($data as $info)
    {
        if(!isset($rst[$info["employee_num"]]))
            $rst[$info["employee_num"]]=$info;
        else
            $rst[$info["employee_num"]]["amount"]+=$info["amount"];
    }
    return array_values($rst);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $array is the original array:

```
$outputArray = array();
foreach ($array as $employeeArray) {
    $outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_name']]['employee_num'] = $employeeArray['employee_num'];
    $outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_name']]['employee_name'] = $employeeArray['employee_name'];
    $outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_name']]['amount'] += $employeeArray['amount'];
}
print_r($outputArray);
```

The keys of `$outputArray` will be the employee's name. If you want to match by the employee_num, simply use `$outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_num']]` instead of `$outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_name']]`.

Comment: I want to get the sum of amounts for each user, but your code just get the last amount entry for each user.

Comment: @ThiliniIW Oops, I made an edit to my solution. Check out the line `$outputArray[$employeeArray['employee_name']]['amount'] += $employeeArray['amount'];`. I used `+=` instead of `=`.